# I did gps location listener but my location updates need permission?

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I did gps location listener but my location updates need permission?

```
public abstract class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager mng;
    private TextView txt1, txt2;
    private LocationListener receiver;

    private void init() {

        mng = (LocationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        mng.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 1.0F, receiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to add permissions to android manifest xml.

For location you will need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

And then, for android Marshmallow and above you will need runtime permissions.

Please find info here

[docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

[example](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Good libraries that will make your life much easier:

[Karumi/Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

[MarshmallowPermissionManager](https://github.com/RurioLuca/MarshmallowPermissionManager)

Comment: I try that of a dozen times but didnt work eventually ı get a permission error

Comment: if you add runtime permissions, if you add manifest permissions, then something in your code is not right...@AydınVardar